# Append .keyword to fieldname in NEST elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

Imagine I have my query as:

```
.Query(query =>
            query.Bool(b => b.Must(m =>     
                m.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.userName).Value(string.Format("*{0}*", searchModel.username).Suffix("keyword")))
)));
```

the output query (from DeubgInformation) will be like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "wildcard": {
                        "userName": "*alex*"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": []
        }
    }
}
```

how'ever this does not work. it needs the ".keyword" to be appended at the endof username. The query below works, but I can not generate it through NEST:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "wildcard": {
                        "userName.keyword": "*alex*"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": []
        }
    }
}
```

any idea how to make NEST to add the ".keyword" at the end of the field name? (of course in Fluent fashion, otherwise `w.Field("userName.keyword")` works)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Suffix()` call needs to be part of the member access expression

```
.Query(query => query
    .Bool(b => b
        .Must(m => m
            .Wildcard(w => w
                .Field(f => f.userName.Suffix("keyword"))
                .Value(string.Format("*{0}*", searchModel.username)
            )
        )
    )
));
```